# SQL Server 2008: Parameters with T-SQL statements

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to know if it is possible to show a parameter with some T-SQL statement.

For example, there is a PARAMETERIZATION parameter. One can set it with such statement:

```
SET PARAMETERIZATION FORCED
```

How to know parameter's status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `DATABASEPROPERTY()`. Something like this:

```
select DATABASEPROPERTY(DB_NAME(), 'IsParameterizationForced')
```

Note that the possible values for `SET PARAMETERIZATION xxx` are `SIMPLE` and `FORCED`. This query will return 1 or 0 depending on whether the current setting is `FORCED`.

Comment: great, this is what is exactly wanted :)